# Why does my ajax code keep firing a GET request when I specify POST even when I have tried both type and method options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is not a duplicate question. This is a unique question because I have already tried using both 'type' and 'method' options.

I have used jquery's ajax method many times and have not had problems with it, but I am working on this project where I have to make a simple POST request via ajax and for some reason it will only let me do GET requests, even when I specify that I want a POST request.

I tried using the method option

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/pets/pet_contact/",
    method: "POST", 
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
    },
    data: data
});
```

I also tried using the type

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/pets/pet_contact/",
    type: "POST", 
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
    },
    data: data
});
```

whenever I fire the ajax request I look at my inspector in chrome and see that it is sending GET requests every time. Anyone have an idea why it would be doing this?

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: What is `data` in your code?

Comment: Did you consider [**reading the documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)? It's far superior to guessing

Comment: or simply use [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: In addition to mentioning the version of jQuery, it could also help to mention your browser and its version.

Comment: @j08691 jQuery v1.11.2

Comment: @qdev I actually also tried useing $.post() instead and it was still doing GET requests.

Comment: So either something is overriding the Ajax calls on the client and setting it to get, cached code is running, or is the server redirecting and making it a GET?

Comment: are you submitting a form?

Comment: hmmm. could possibly be the server. I am using django cms and the views work a little different.  Thanks for the input. I will continue on.

Comment: @SpencerCooley I know you just mentioned you are moving on. But, how are you able to say its GET request from the inspector  ? What does the server say ?

Comment: You can look at the network activity in the browser developer tools on chrome. so when I click the button to make the ajax request fire I can see that it is a GET request. I also know it is a get request because on the url I am requesting I am not allowing GET requests so get a 

Status Code:405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Comment: The duplicate question also mentions the possibility of redirects.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev ahhh, yes it was a redirect. this is in django cms so all the urls have /en/ in front of it. if that is left out it redirects /your/url/ to /en/your/url/  . So this was not a javascript problem it was an issues with django cms url structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the shorthand for ajax, like:

Original code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/pets/pet_contact/",
    type: "POST", 
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result)
    },
    data: data
});
```

Shorthand

```
$mydata = {
   action:'myaction',
   variable:$('#myvariable').val(),
   othervariable:$('#othervariable').val()      
};

$.post('path/file.php', $mydata, function(result) {
  console.log(result)
});
```

In a PHP file, you can catch all the data on:

```
<?php

       $action        = $_POST['action'];
       $variable      = $_POST['variable'];
       $othervariable = $_POST['othervariable'];

       switch ($action) {
           case 'myaction' :
             echo $variable.' and '.$othervariable;
           break;
       }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the content-type of your data:

```
var settings = {
  "async": false,
  "crossDomain": false,
  "url": "/pets/pet_contact/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\r\n \"var1\": \"value 1\",\r\n \"var2\": \"value 2\",\r\n \"var3\": \"value 3"\r\n }"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Form vars:

```
var settings = {
  "async": false,
  "crossDomain": false,
  "url": "/pets/pet_contact/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "var1": "value 1",
    "var2": "value 2",
    "var3": "value 3"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```